# pagination issue in jqModal window

Tags: jquery, pagination, jqmodal, jquery-pagination

I am very new to jquery. I have one jsp as main page with a table and in one columm some data with hyperlink. When user clicks on the data it opens a pop up to display the details.

The code is like:

```
$('body').append($('.jqmWindow'));
    $('#dialog').jqm({
      ajax : '@href',
      model : true,
      trigger : 'a.blue'
    });
```

This is the function which is triggering the popup or modal(which is actually an another jsp).
The issue is I integrated Spring pagination in the controller for the first time the data is coming in the popup but, when I click on next page it opens in the browser window instead of the pop up.

Below is the jsp which is getting displayed in the modal/popup

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tag" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" %>
<% pageContext.setAttribute("newLineChar", "\n"); %> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".link-message").click(function(){
        $(".message-view.active").hide();
        $(".message-view.hide").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".message-view").toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("active");
    });
      $('body').append($('.jqmWindow'));
        $('#dialog').jqm({
          ajax : '@action',
          modal : true,
          trigger : 'form.blue'
        });
});
```

Exit

My jsp content

```
<c:url var="pagedLink" value="/secure/eventDetail/viewConversationDetail" scope="request">
            <c:param name="d-4022873-p" value="~"/>
            <c:if test="${not empty param.class}"><c:param name="class" value="${param.class}"/></c:if>
            <c:if test="${not empty param.deviceUid}"><c:param name="deviceUid" value="${param.deviceUid}"/></c:if>
            <c:if test="${not empty param.eventType}"><c:param name="eventType" value="${param.eventType}"/></c:if>
            <c:if test="${not empty param.eventId}"><c:param name="eventId" value="${param.eventId}"/></c:if>
          </c:url>
    <ul class="nav-links-popup float-right pad">
     <li class="blue"><tag:paging pagedLink="${pagedLink}" pagedListHolder="${eventsHolder}"></tag:paging></li>
    </ul>
</form:form>
```

How can I make the modal to work fine with pagination.

Any help will be